# Check whether canvas is black

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I have a script which takes a picture and creates black and white R, G and B channels. And I would like to count how many channels have something on them (black = no colour, white = colour data).

It works by going through every single pixel and saving data in 3 different canvas elements. Each one showing different channel.

It works great but when I give a Red and Blue picture only, the green channel (obviously) is completely black.

So my question is, how do I check whether the canvas is completely black? I would like to avoid looping through every pixel in every channel to see if it's all black.

cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok I've tested a few things and the easiest solution I could come up with was creating a 1x1 offscreen canvas, then drawing either your image or your original canvas you want to check for data on it, scaled down to 1 pixel and check it (I also added basic caching).

It's not a precise check, and the result depends on how the pixel data is distributed in the original image, so as GameAlchemist noted, you may loop through all the pixels anyway if the result of the check is 0 if you want accurate results.

```
function quickCheck(img){
    var i = arguments.callee; //caching the canvas&context in the function
    if(!i.canvas){i.canvas = document.createElement("canvas")} 
    if(!i.ctx)   {i.ctx    = i.canvas.getContext("2d")}

    i.canvas.width=i.canvas.height = 1;
    i.ctx.drawImage(img,0,0,1,1);
    var result = i.ctx.getImageData(0,0,1,1);
    return result.data[0]+result.data[1]+result.data[2]+result.data[3];
}
```

Comment: Not sure if that would work, because the black canvas has data per se. All pixels are just black.

Comment: for the example you can check http://designer.vetosports.com/admin/ .. go to add designs and just upload Red and Blue picture.. or blue and green..

Comment: Yeah but isn't it what you want to check? ->  _So my question is, how do I check whether the canvas is completely black? I would like to avoid looping through every pixel in every channel to see if it's all black_ **vs** _Not sure if that would work, because the black canvas has data per se. All pixels are just black_

Comment: (if you are waiting for me to go to your website or something, sorry I don't see a reason why I should. Post everything relevant here)

Comment: moost efficient and elegant ! 
@TomaszGolinski : could you, besides explaining that a black canvas is black, explain more why this would not be a fit ?

Comment: mmm... second thought : 1) you can't use scale, or i don't see how. So i used 9 args flavor of putImageData. But 2) you get false negative with this one, because of the rounding : below a given number of drawn points, output is (#0000). So this might only be used as a first test : if 1x canvas is non-black, then original is non-black. If black -> check by hand.

Comment: You're right, thanks for pointing out, it's indeed not a precise check and your suggested putImagedData probably is probably slightly more efficient than the transformation. I'm going to test it while I think about a solution for the precision problem :)

Comment: damn now I ended up posting code... but as I know me there'll be a bug in this code somewhere anyway so it can't be just copy pasted^^

Comment: @Winchestro. I just visited the questioner's site.  His app is not as complicated as you (and I) assumed.  All he's doing is dividing the r,g,b channels of 2 user-uploaded images.  IMHO, no need for complicated solutions here...just iterate the getImageData pixel arrays for 2 images (a few milliseconds of simple looping required).  Cheers!

Comment: @markE Oh snap hehe. But maybe it will still be of help for someone else :)

Answer (score 0):

**You must iterate the canvas's pixel data**--no magic method to avoid that.

The performance cost of iterating through 2 images is trivial (2 images = your front image and back image).

*[ Removed un-necessary part of answer after visiting questioner's site ]*

Comment: looping by hand is waaaay more efficient than using every(). while( !ch[i++] && (i<length) ); then test for i==length.  (speed should be around 10X faster)

Comment: @GameAlchemist I don't find a material performance difference between `while` and `every` on canvas-sized arrays.  When using a canvas sized array then Chrome35, FF29 & IE11 all report sub-millisecond performance.  I'll take your word that `while` is faster but for this purpose it is a "difference without a distinction" (not significant). :-)

Comment: Boring dammage control rhetoric. You can do better. What's true is that hand-written loop is 10X faster, as jsperf can show, and that in this case, the performance gap does not matter at all.

Comment: "Boring damage(sic) control rhetoric"--Ouch!  My real-world test iterated an actual canvas imageData pixel array (canvas size=300x300 with the discovery pixel at 290,290). In that performance test `while` and `every` completed with **no material real-world time difference.**  Part of good project management is knowing what is material and what is not material--in this case choosing between while & every is not material.  Anyway...still love-ya man! :-)

Comment: You are misusing (sic) :-). 300x300 is not a real use case. HD is 70 times bigger. Good project management involve dealing with real use case - HD screens -, and also with much slower devices such as smartphones/tablets/... (20 times slower or more). While loop is so simple there just not a single reason to use every(). Not one. For the love of efficient graphic code ;-)

Comment: @GameAlchemist: Even using iPhone S5 Retina resolution the array is iterated in <125ms on IE & Chrome.  But...ahem...uhhh...the array is iterated in a horrible 2500ms on FF (I guess FF has not yet implemented the new native ES5 array methods). So I guess I have to concede the point that `while` is currently better than `every`.  BTW, I hope you will similarly concede that my answer is correct--"iterate the canvas's pixel data"?

Comment: You and i might only be wrong on details (!!! :-) ). Sure iterating is the way to go, you're right. Btw don't know if you're aware of the new blending modes of the canvas :http://dev.w3.org/fxtf/compositing-1/#porterduffcompositingoperators_srcatop Here extracting, say, red channel could be done by GPU by using multiply and fillRect with #FF0000. Nice !!

Comment: @GameAlchemist. Yep, Blending simplifies things greatly. IE lags behind in implementing it (probably in IE vNext) and Chrome's implementation is buggy from version to version.  I'm guessing early 2015 for Blending to be universal and stable in the latest browsers.  Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Another quick check would be to calculate the sum of the image data. If the sum is equal to the amount of pixels in the canvas times 255, it is probably all black. There is a small chance that some other combination of pixels could cause the sum to be equal to the same number, but the chance is very low (unless you are looping through all the canvas combinations).